# Как return'уть это?

Tags: java, android

Скорее всего, тут всё элементарно, но как return'уть 1-й элемент ArrayList'a?

```
private String scan() {
    wifiApManager.getClientList(false, new FinishScanListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFinishScan(final ArrayList<ClientScanResult> clients) {

            for (ClientScanResult clientScanResult : clients) {
                return clientScanResult.getIpAddr()
            }

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: `return` - действует только на свой метод. Из `onFinishScan` нельзя вызвать `return` метода `scan()`. Вместо этого нужно из `onFinishScan` вызвать код, который должен использовать результат и передать результат ему для дальнейшей работы.

Comment: @woesss, спасибо огромное!

Answer (score 0):

Метод get() с аргументом первого элемента  (в java нумерация массивов начинается с 0, так что скорее всего Вам нужно 0). получится что-то вроде этого (не проверял):

```
ArrayList ARRAY = clientScanResult.getIpAddr();
return ARRAY.get(0);
```

Comment: суть в том, что clientScanResult.getIpAddr() как раз этот элемент и есть. Нужно просто сделать так, чтобы после вызова scan() возвращалось значение clientScanResult.getIpAddr()

Comment: `return clients.get(0).getIpAddr();`

Comment: @woesss, можете, пожалуйста, код полностью написать в виде ответа?

Answer (score 0):

А так нельзя ?

```
 @Override
        public ЗначениеIp onFinishScan(ArrayList<ClientScanResult> clients) {

            return clients.get(0).getIpAddr();

        }
```

UPD Не просмотрел ответы, такой уже был